# Can you pass different Material-ui icons as props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I am wondering how I would add different Icons? This is what I have so far but the icon does not show in my UI?

my props thought that would work

When I add the Facebook button it doesn't show like it does on the button I added

```js
const Item = ({ name = 'Item Name', tags = [] }, icon) => {
  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} spacing={2}>
      <Paper elevation={6}>
        <Grid container justifyContent="flex-start" spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            {/*Notice the name is in {} since it is a variable*/}
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            {icon}
            <div>{icon}</div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            {tags.map((tag, idx) => {
              return <Chip key={idx} label={tag} color={'secondary'} />;
            })}
          </Grid>

          <Grid item>
            <Button endIcon={<FacebookIcon />} color="primary" variant="contained">
              Button 1
            </Button>
            <Button color="secondary" variant="contained">
              Button 2
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
};

const MyView = () => {
  return (
    <Widget>
      <Grid container spacing={4}>
        <Item icon={<FacebookIcon />} name={jsonData.name} tags={jsonData.tags} />
        <Item name="test paper" tag={'chip2'}></Item>
        <Item name={jsonData.name} tags={jsonData.tags} />
      </Grid>
    </Widget>
  );
};

export default MyView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mistake is there    `const Item = ({name="Item Name", tags=[],icon} ) => {`
you must import icon from the props object not like a parameter. you should notice that Item was not used like a function with parameter and it is a react component :

```
import FacebookOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FacebookOutlined';
const Item = ({name="Item Name", tags=[],icon} ) => {
    return (
        <>


            <Grid item xs={12} spacing={2}>
                <Paper elevation={6}>
                    <Grid container justifyContent="flex-start" spacing={3}>

                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            {/*Notice the name is in {} since it is a variable*/}
                            <h1>{name}</h1>
                            {icon}
                            <div>{icon}</div>
                        </Grid>


                    </Grid>
                </Paper>

            </Grid>

        </>
    )
}

const Add = (props) => {

    return (
                <Item icon={<FacebookOutlinedIcon/>} name="test" tags={[]}/>
    );
};

export default Add;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much new to react and its really amazing what it can do! The community is really helpful.

Comment: @Carlos if you want you can give me a green check